# ROS/ROS2 for multi agent system

Tags: ros, multi-agent

Does anybody know how to use ROS/ROS2 for the multi-agent system? I know there are other software for multi agent, but I heard that ROS is suitable for this. Does anybody know the specific ideas?

Answer (score 0):

ROS is a middleware framework for creating a distributed system of nodes based on the publish/subscribe methodology. It can certainly be used for a multi-agent system. You should read through [the ros wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials). It has a lot of great info and is a very easy way to start learning the ideas.

Comment: Do you have some examples for me to learn? May I ask, if my simulation environment is in Windows, because ROS is in UBUNTU, is it still possible to use ROS as multi-agent?

Comment: I don’t really have anything super specific because what you’re asking is a very large and broad question. I’d start at the basic tutorials on the ROS wiki and just work through those. If you’re hoping to use Windows you’ll have to use ROS2 as ROS1 doesn’t have support.

Answer (score 0):

we're currently working on a BDI framework for ROS2 targeting Multi Agent Systems (MAS), thus facilitating its development. Repository is [here](https://github.com/devis12/ROS2-BDI) and user's documentation [here](https://devis12.github.io/ROS2-BDI.github.io/). The plans are dynamically computed via a PDDL 2.1 based planning system (which is PlanSys2). It's still under development, so there can be bugs here and there. We're currently try to solve them and then the idea is to lean toward a more flexible reasoning behaviour, while keeping in consideration real time constraints and/or computational feasibility of the plan execution.

If that might fulfill your needs, give it a look and share your feedback!